# How to send to print an image inside a div?

Tags: javascript

This is what I am doing:

```
<div id="printableArea">
    <img src="belly.png">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="printDiv('printableArea')" value="print" />

function printDiv(printableArea) {
    var printContents = document.getElementById("printableArea").innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    window.print();
}
```

That is showing in the dialog the file name and the whole document and not just the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
popup = window.open();
popup.document.write(printContents);
popup.focus(); //for IE
popup.print()
```

Comment: if i put that inside the function, the dialog shows me an empty blank page

Comment: You should keep the printContents variables that contains your content, or else you'll get a blank page.

Comment: I created a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rd8f6pLf/, document.write is replaced with other method because jsfiddle.com not allowing it.

Comment: ok yes, i made it working but it is opening a new windows too as well as the popUp print dialog. I would like not to open another window but keep the same and open only the dialog popUp, is it possible?

Comment: we are almost there, but the recovering initial view which is what i want, keeping the initial view, is creating issues and it breaks

Comment: Fiddle is just a quick sample, the way to solve your problem.Hide and show you can do more efficient, to not causing issues.